# Fail to infer generic parameter of a parent interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Failing to get proper type inference, any ideas on how to fix it?

```js
interface I<T> {};
class C implements I<string> {};

function test<T, B extends I<T>>(b: B): T {
  return null as any; // just to make it compile
}

// expecting for x to be string but instead having it type 'unknown'
let x = test(new C);
```

Comment: Looks like a typo  - try `new C()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior.  See [the TypeScript FAQ: "Why doesn't type inference work on this interface: `interface Foo<T> { }`?"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--).

TypeScript's type system is [structural and not nominal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html).  So type `Foo` and type `Bar` are the same if they have the same *structure* (e.g., names of keys and types of values), not if they were declared with the same name.  Your interface:

```
interface I<T> {};
```

does not use the type parameter `T` at all in the structure.  No matter what you specify for `T`, the type `I<T>` is the same as the empty interface `{}`.  And thus, `I<string>` and `I<number>` are identical to each other and to `{}`.  Essentially `I<T>` *throws away* all information about `T`.  And so the compiler is unable to infer `string` from `I<string>`, since there is no `string` in `{}`.

---

To fix this, you'd need to actually use `T` structurally, such as:

```
interface I<T> {
  someProperty: T // <-- T is part of the structure now
};
class C implements I<string> {
  someProperty = "hello"
};
```

Now a value of type `I<string>` will have a property named `someProperty` of type `string`, while one of `I<number>` will have a property named `someProperty` of type `number`.  You can tell those apart.  And so the inference you are looking for will happen correctly:

```
function test<T>(b: I<T>): T {
  return b.someProperty;
}

let x = test(new C); // string
console.log(x.toUpperCase()) // HELLO
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIB4AqA+ZBvAKGWQGcB7AWwgAUoyAHaMATwC5lMCBfAbgIQA2cEiWQBhZMAr0BEKuFEYSYKKADmuQsXJVaDJs2QBeZACIAFhAECyp7nwIwAriARhgZEMkjKs2ABQARuwYOACU7Jj4RMhQEGBOUF6BAHQ6NHSMUCx8XAQEsmDIAB7G3hDK-iAQAO7iYTzIAPRNpCrq-J7ksik2av7FKWBkAKr0WWLCEP5hYc2tABIAogAyKwDyQA)

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that is close to your idea, but seems like the solution doesn't work on it when `T` of `I<T>` is not used. I think it will be better though

```
interface I<T = string> {
    a: T // if T isn't be used, function test will return unknown
};
class C implements I<string> {
    a = '1'
};

function test<B>(b: B): B extends I<infer R>? R : never {
  return null as any; // just to make it compile
}

let x = test(new C()); // string
```

Comment: This looks good. The two issues seem to be that `I` and `C` don't have any properties on them that hold the generic type `T`, as well as that TS inference does not seem to work "backwards", i.e. TS can't figure out the type of T even if it knows B. Here's an even simpler example showing the second issue: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwKYEMAmAeAKgGkQEFFUAPKVMTAZ2ICd70BPPAPjYAp1GAuYgJT9ciAN4AoRFMT1UUEPSQ96AbQAMAXQDc4gL7jxEBDSiI6AXhQZMnFQCIAjACYAzHcKPXAFjsaBWxAB6QLN+cABrMDgAdzBxIA